# new Outlook profile creation with script

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-2016

I am in an Exchange 2010/Office 365 migration project. I'm working on Exchange 2010/Office 365 migration. In test environment where I successfully migrated the mail boxes with cutover migration to the cloud.

The next step would be the development of a script, which should create the new profile for the Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2016 clients. I found a script, which creates the necessary registry components, but the Outlook doesn’t start.

Comment: Would you please post the script you've tried and Outlook's error.

Comment: What kind of script are you using? Are you creating a PRF file?

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to create a new profile:

1. Build a .prf file with the desired settings and then run Outlook with the /importprf command-line switch to load and process the profile information from that file. See [How to create an Outlook Profile File (*.PRF)](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/config/create-outlook-profile-file-prf/)
2. Extended MAPI provides the `IProfAdmin` interface which allows you programmatically create a profile without user interaction. See [How to create MAPI profiles without installing Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306962/how-to-create-mapi-profiles-without-installing-outlook) for more information.
3. Use third-party utilities for creating profiles. I guess all of them will be built on top of the `IProfAdmin` interface.

Also you may find the following links helpful:

- [How to: Programmatically Create a Profile in Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt707568.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [How To: Create an Outlook profile using MFCMAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt723322.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)